# How to remove first and last square brackets from JSON

Tags: json, python-2.7

I am storing the below JSON in Hadoop and unable to load it in Hive table because of first and last square brackets in JSON. Stored JSON file in Hadoop looks like as defined below

```
[
  {
    firstname:"kunal",
    lastname:"gupta",
    age:20
  },
  {
    firstname:"Abhishek",
    lastname:"gautam",
    age:20
  },
  {
    firstname:"Neha",
    lastname:"gupta",
    age:20
  }
]
```

Please help me to remove the first and last square bracket using Python script so that JSON looks like defined below:-

```
{
    firstname:"kunal",
    lastname:"gupta",
    age:20
},
{
    firstname:"Abhishek",
    lastname:"gautam",
    age:20
},
{
    firstname:"Neha",
    lastname:"gupta",
    age:20
}
```

Comment: Have you tried trimming the JSON string?

Comment: How did you notice you're missing the brackets? What you have is proper JSON format. What exactly does Hive expect?

Comment: What you mean by trimming here ?

Comment: @ReutSharabani, i loaded the same JSON file without square brackets then it loaded in Hive table and i am able to query also.

Comment: How big is the file? How big can it be? How did you load it to Hive? (This is important...)

Comment: @ReutSharabani, I have the multiple JSON file with same format.
Minimum file size of JSON can be 6 KB and maximum can be 2 MB.

Created a table in Hive using following command:-

**CREATE TABLE json_table ( json string ) row format delimited lines terminated by ',';** 

I have loaded the file using following command:-

**LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH  '/tmp/simple.json' INTO TABLE json_table;**